# How to tag the outgoing packets with the correct VLAN ID?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, ip, vlan

I have a virtual machine CentoS running on VMware workstation 12 player on my PC (windows 7) and i am trying to configure the VM to be able to reach my client network.

Please see the attached photo to have an idea about what i am trying to do.

My client gave me 2 differents VLANs for the services running on the VM. Before configuring the VM i tried to test if i can reach the network from my PC so i created 2 VLAN with IDs (112, 134) and i gave them the Static IP address provided by the client 192.168.100.3 and 192.168.100.11 respectively and i was able to ping the GWs and reach the network.

Then i moved to the VM and i kept the VLAN created on the PC, and i created 1 virtual interface. eth0 and eth0:1 are bridged automaticaly to the VLANs.

```
eth0 
IPADDR=192.168.100.3
NETMASK=255.255.255.248
GW=192.168.100.1

eth0:1
IPADDR=192.168.100.10
NETMASK=255.255.255.248
GW=192.168.100.9
```

After this configuration i was able to reach the GW 192.168.100.1 but not 192.168.100.9

Then i deleted all the VLANs on my PC and i created two VLANs on the VM it self :

```
Device=eth0
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes

Device=eth0.112
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.100.2
NETMASK=255.255.255.248
GW=192.168.100.1
VLAN=yes

Device=eth0.134
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.100.10
NETMASK=255.255.255.248
GW=192.168.100.9
VLAN=yes
```

But with this configuration i was not able to reach any on the GWs at all. Please tell your suggestions.

[image: Network]

Comment: You need Virtual Network Editor enabled on VmWarePlayer which by default isn't and you need it in order to turn on automatic bridging, then set VmNet# to use your vlan